# twentyten submenu CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I am using a twentyten child theme for a website that I am creating and I am having a lot of trouble accessing the "current_item" selector on the sub menu items

I can format the main menu items via:

```
#access ul li.current_page_item a{}
```

I have tried:

```
#access ul ul li.current_page_item a{}
```

or the standard twentyten css entries:

```
#access ul li.current_page_item > a,
#access ul li.current_page_ancestor > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-parent > a { }
```

but neither of them work on the sub-menu items...

What I want to do is change the background and text color of the current submenu item. Any ideas how to access it?

You can check out the current status here:

http://stuck-mueller.de/beta.php?page_id=47

The currently selected sub-menu item is "Estrich" and what I want to change is its background and text color.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: your site is not displaying correctly. it seems that it fails to load styles

Comment: There is no CSS at all. [http://stuck-mueller.wit/wp-content/themes/stuckmueller/style.css](http://stuck-mueller.wit/wp-content/themes/stuckmueller/style.css) this is empty

Comment: thanks - the link for the css was still to my local machine, it should be fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the `background-color` and `Text` color of `current menu item` then you can achieve this by adding the property in following css class (`style.css : line 98`)

```
#access ul li.current_page_item a
{
   color: Yellow;
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: yes, that is what I am already doing and it is not the problem - what I want to change is the color and background of the currently selected sub-menu item (left sidebar)

Comment: ok but when I click any of the subitem, it takes me to other page(not having proper styles). but btw if you want to change the color and BG for the sidebar item, you can do it by `widget-area a:active` class

Comment: Yes, the navigation doesnt work properly because the I just uploaded the website for testing pourposes. There is no need to use the navigation however...

Comment: ok then I have seen that which class is applying on current active link. so you can try above mention class `widget-area a:active` to change the color and BG of current selected sub-item

Comment: Ah, i see the problem with my link... since you cant navigate you cant get to the page where the sub-menu item is the current page. I have updated the link:

http://stuck-mueller.de/beta.php?page_id=47

the current sub-menu item is "Estrich"
The widget-area a:active selector changes the background color of the link when it is currently being clicked. What I want to change is the background color of the "current_page" sub-menu item. (In the example I want change only the "Estrich" menu item.)

Comment: ok I got it. you have applied `widget_subpages_current_page` this class over current selected item but this class isn't specify in css file. so simply you can do is just add this class in css and set color property in this class

Comment: Thanks! that does the trick :) I guess the plugin that creates the sub-menu must have added that class and was overwriting the twentyten values.